SOAP implementation in Android App Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
I generated java files, from WSDL file, all the files import jakarta dependencies.
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

I used wsimport (3.0.2) to generate this file. My main problem is to create service class to connect with server. The wsimport create for me 2 different files:
interface WSTabletService and java class SysServiceTablet.
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 3.0.2
 * Generated source version: 3.0

I tried to use it like this
class SysTabletServiceHandler {

    private val WSDL_URL = "correct_address"

    private val SERVICE_QNAME = QName("http://SysServiceTablet/", "SysServiceTablet")

    fun getWSTabletService(): WSTabletService? {
        return try {
            val wsdlUrl = URL(WSDL_URL)
            val service = Service.create(wsdlUrl, SERVICE_QNAME)
            service.getPort(WSTabletService::class.java) 
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }

}

But I have error
jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
The dependencies that I have now are:
`    implementation 'jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2'

`
but I got problem with duplicated dependencies. But if I delete everything expect first one then app starts and I have something like this:
Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
in this line:
Service.create(wsdlUrl, SERVICE_QNAME) (full code above)
I want to add headers to authentication and connect to server with request. I tried delete everything and start from the bottom again but I found this problem when tried to override headers.

Perhaps Jakarta SOAP is designed to be used on the JVM, not on Android.
